# PyCharm/Python. Code doesn't run. Immediately receiving "Getting Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, fedora-25

I recently switched my workstation and reinstalled all my environment on Fedora 25. 
When attempting to run any part of my project (I run PyTest tests) I always end up getting "Process finished with exit code 0" message in debug.

Here's the full debug message:

```
    /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/share/java/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 46537 --file /home/pavel/Documents/integration_tests/cfme/tests/containers/test_containers_default_project_replicators.py
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/usr/bin/python2.7" "/usr/share/java/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: process 10166 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)
/home/pavel/Documents/integration_tests/utils/log.py:222: UserWarning: clearing configuration is bad
  del(conf['env'])
```

The project I am trying to run is actually open sourced and is here for reference:
https://github.com/ManageIQ/integration_tests

Comment: `exit code 0` is the general exit code and usually means that your code ran successfully. What exactly were you hoping to achieve with your code and what actually occurred?

Comment: The exit code you mention above is not in this snippet. Please check.

Comment: @MKesper the exit code appears just beneath the code I posted

Comment: @ChristianW. I try to run one of the tests here: https://github.com/ManageIQ/integration_tests Check the path in the debug code

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the problem was that the I tried to run it as Python Run/Debug configuration instead of Py.test run/debug configuration.

From 
[How do I configure PyCharm to run py.test tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397063/how-do-i-configure-pycharm-to-run-py-test-tests)

Please go to File | Settings | Tools | Python Integrated Tools and change the default test runner to py.test. Then you'll get the py.test option to create tests instead of the unittest one.

Comment: In my case I also needed to delete the old "Run configuration", and then re-run the test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, along with the rest of great suggestions, somehow content root was not defined.
Solution: File|Settings|Project Structure -> Add Content Root (Here you select your project folder)

*It took me a looong time for this, hope that this will help somebody :)

Comment: this commend is no longer relevant, pycharm does not have these options in the menu