# Why does pycharm not recognize my pytest tests and show the test output?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm new to pytest and am trying to write testing modules for my application.   My directory structure is:

```
broker/
broker/tests
broker/tests/conftest.py
broker/tests/test_db.py
broker/db.py
```

I want to test the db.py module.

I configure pycharm to use pytest as my test runner.    When I run the test_db.py in pycharm I get:

```
/Users/cbogdon/virtualenv/platinum-onboard/bin/python /Users/cbogdon/coding/platinum-onboard/broker/tests/test_db.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It's almost like pycharm is not executing the pytest.   Even if I right click on the green arrow to the left of one of my testing functions a menu appears and shows I can click:   "Run 'pytest for test_db.py::TestDBFunctions::test_valid_db'"

If I run it at the command line using:

```
python -m pytest --setup-show tests/test_db.py
```

I get the appropriate test output.

```
 python -m pytest --setup-show tests/test_db.py 
========================================================== test session starts ===========================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /Users/cbogdon/coding/platinum-onboard/broker, inifile:
collected 4 items                                                                                                                        

tests/test_db.py 
        tests/test_db.py::TestDBFunctions::test_uuid.
        tests/test_db.py::TestDBFunctions::test_invalid_dbF
        tests/test_db.py::TestDBFunctions::test_valid_db.
        tests/test_db.py::TestDBFunctions::test_already_created_database.

================================================================ FAILURES ================================================================
____________________________________________________ TestDBFunctions.test_invalid_db _____________________________________________________

self = <test_db.TestDBFunctions object at 0x102606438>

    def test_invalid_db(self):
>       ret = db.initialize_database()
E       TypeError: initialize_database() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dbname'

tests/test_db.py:14: TypeError
=================================================== 1 failed, 3 passed in 0.08 seconds ==================================================
```

Is there something special I need to do in PyCharm?

Sorry for the newbie question, but I just can't figure this out one bit!

Answer (score 29):

Please make sure that `Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Default test runner` is set to `pytest` & clean cache and restart pycharm (especially if this setting was changed in past)[image]

(image courtesy of [Brandon Braner](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002838580-Why-does-PyCharm-not-run-pytest-testing-for-my-application-?page=1#community_comment_360000887539))

Comment: The Default Test Runner was set.   I did clean cache and restart pycharm and I get the same result.   It isn't showing any test output!

Comment: Changing the default test runner like this worked for me. Be aware though that if you already run that class before, you also need to delete the run configuration which got created! Only then will PyCharm automatically create a new pytest configuration. Otherwise it will just try to use the old run configuration, which is a default python run config and therefore does not execute your tests

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer:   I had to:

In the Run/Debug Configurations window (**Ctrl+Alt+F10** or go to **Run > Edit configurations..**) click on the + button found on the upper left corner. Go to Python tests and select py.test. Click OK button.

On the left pane you can see Python tests is created. In the right pane for the Name text box give the value as py.test in module_name.py You should always prefix the Python test file name with the words py.test in.

For the Target text box specify the path to the Python test file.

For the Working directory text box specify the path to the directory which has the Python test files.

Click on OK button.

For whatever this worked and now it works!

Comment: Please provide a screenshot - it's a bit tricky to follow your steps

Comment: To open _Run/Debug Configurations_ press **Ctrl+Alt+F10** or go to **Run > Edit configurations..**

Comment: Also, it helps me to remove all existing test configurations from `Run/Debug Configurations` as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48074735/19813684

Answer (score 2):

If the other solutions don't work, make sure to set the content root correctly  so that your code is properly indexed and tests can be detected. PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root -> Select the root folder as content root.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I could run my tests perfectly in the terminal but it failed to run using PyCharm. It turns out that if you select your `test` directory and run it, PyCharm automatically sets the `test` directory as the **working directory** as opposed to the `root`, which caused import issues in my `conftest.py`. Hence, this broke my tests when using PyCharm as opposed to the terminal.

**Solution**: manually change your Working Directory to the root

[image: Imaging showing steps to change working directory]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other two answers and realized there is one more step to go, if you previously set nose or other tests type as default.

Open **Run/Debug Configurations** > **Python tests** > click **+** button > **Pytest** > In **target:** choose the **Module name** > **Ctrl+Space** so it could do the code completion for each unit test.

[screenshot  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8law.png)