# IntelliJ Python plugin pytest code runs but debug doesn't work

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pytest

I have an issue debugging python tests using pytest on IntelliJ IDE with the **python plugin**

the tests can be run (they have the green arrow) and after running them they are executed correctly but I can't debug them.

I already configured my run/debug configuration as was answered here: [How do I configure PyCharm to run py.test tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397063/how-do-i-configure-pycharm-to-run-py-test-tests)

here is my IDE: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGPpo.png)

Execution log:

> collecting ... collected 3 items
>
> test_demo_test.py::test_uppercase
>
> test_demo_test.py::test_reversed
>
> test_demo_test.py::test_some_primes
>
> ============================== 3 passed in 0.07s ===============================
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>
> PASSED                                 [ 33%]
>
> PASSED                                  [ 66%]
>
> PASSED                               [100%]

Comment: Did you hit debug button ? , it is next to run button or it could be your breakpoint is not executing. May be put breakpoint beginning of first statement

Comment: What happens when you try to debug? Do you see an error, does the execution skips breakpoints? Please provide more information.